# How can I find the inverse of number using Fermat's Little Theorem or Euler's Theorem?

Tags: inverse, cryptography, totient-function, fermat-numbers

Specifically the inverse of 101 and with n = 31200.

$101^{-1} \mod 31200 $

Comment: Extended Euclidean algorithm is the way to go. If you can find integers $a,b$ such that $1 = 101 a + 31200 b$, then reducing the equation mod $31200$, you can see that the $a$ you found is indeed the inverse to 101.

Comment: This is true, but I'm looking for a solution that uses Fermat's Little Theorem or Euler's Theorem.

Comment: Why though? Can you explain what you need this problem for (see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question))?

Comment: Euler says that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$, and so in particular $a^{\phi(n) - 1} \mod n$ is the inverse of $a$ for any $a$ relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: This is the approach we need to take in my Cryptography class. I'm already familiar with Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Euler's theorem, $101^{\phi(31200)}=101^{7680}\equiv1\bmod 31200$, so $101^{-1}\equiv101^{7679}\bmod31200$.

This may not be the most efficient way to find ${101}^{-1}$ though.

Comment: So, I've gotten to this point. Now, what would be the approach you take to further reduce the exponent 7679?

Comment: as I indicated, this is not the most practical approach, but you could use repeated squaring and then calculate it as $101^{1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128+256+1024+2048+4096}$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(n)$ to reduce the exponent.

- $n= 31200 = 2^5\cdot 3\cdot 5^2 \cdot 13$
- $\lambda(2^5) = 8,\lambda(3) = 2, \lambda(5^2)=20,\lambda(13)=12$
- $\Rightarrow \lambda(n) = lcm(8,2,20,12)=120$

$$\Rightarrow 101^{120} \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

Remains to find $101^{119}\mod n$. This is quickly done by factoring the module:

- $101^{119} \equiv 13 \mod 32, \:101^{119} \equiv 2\mod 3,\: 101^{119}\equiv 1 \mod 25,\: 101^{119}\equiv 4 \mod 13$.

Now, Chinese remainder theorem gives

$$101^{-1 }\equiv101^{119} \equiv 13901 \pmod {31200}$$